# How to create OG image view?

Tags: organic-groups

I facing issue with `OG 7.2x` and `image`.

I create a group content type and add new field with `image`. After that i upload some picture, and view with `colorbox` working fine.

After that, i create normal view all things is workings well. if i add `contextual(OG member:group id)` and `relationship(member from og node)`, the picture disappeared and nothing display under OG view.

Would you please tell me that how to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi what you can do is that create a content pane from a view display and configure it in the following screen shot listed below.

[image: OG View for displaying content]

Next in the fields section you can add the image field and other fields as per you like.

[image]

```
 ![Add fields accordingly][2]
```

Also you can clone the view that comes default with OG.

```
OG:CONTENT(clone this view and add fields)
```

Hope this helps. :)

Edit:- For displaying images

I havent done anything like this before. But I think you can do this by "rewriting" the result of the url field.

You can do this by clicking the field with the url that you will find under "FIELDS" in your view settings. Then under "Rewrite Results" you can write something like

```
<img src="[image_url]" />
```

here, 'image_url' must be the name of the field. you can verify this in the list displayed under "Replacement Patterns"

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: the Pictures still not display. when i following you step, the image field name appeared,but pictures not displayed.

Comment: @yutaolife Have edited my answer above and added for displaying images...just try if that works.

Comment: Also if you are using Image field type you can try and Click the '+' sign next to Relationships and you should most likely find one under 'Image'. Once a relationship is set up then you should see image in your fields. @yutaolife

Comment: Another helpful resource
http://www.metachunk.com/blog/adding-related-content-view-drupal-7